# Partitioning Scheme on HDD+SSD system

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, partitioning, ssd

I have a fresh Samsung ultrabook with 500GB HDD and a 16 GB SSD. It came with Windows 7 installed. I am going to dual boot with Xubuntu 12.04. The following is the layout as seen from GParted.

```
/dev/sda (500GB HDD)
Partition  FS Type  Label        Size       Used      Flags
/dev/sda1  ntfs     SYSTEM       100MiB     33.59MiB  boot
/dev/sda2  ntfs     -            446.10GiB  32.18GiB  -
/dev/sda3  ntfs     SAMSUNG_REC  19.56GiB   18.62GiB  diag


/dev/sdb (16GB SSD)
Partition  FS Type  Label  Size      Used  Flags
/dev/sdb1  -        -      10.61GiB  -     -
/dev/sdb2  -        -      4.29GiB   -     -
```

sdb2 is being used as Hibernation Partition by Win7. My strategy is as follows:

1. Reduce Windows partition to 60GB
2. Put / on sdb1 (my current root takes 6.8GiB, so 10.6GiB should be sufficient)
3. Put /var as a 2GB partition on sda, after sda2
4. Put /home as a 30GB partition on sda, after /var
5. Use sdb2 as swap
6. Split the remaining sda space into chunks of 100GB, 100GB and ~154GB
7. Putting GRUB on /dev/sda

Are there any improvements to these? Like putting only /boot, /bin and /sbin on sdb1. This would reduce the writes on SSD but would need careful sizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a question about the reasonableness of avoiding write processes to a SSD.

I wouldn't care about it and go for one partition for /, one for /home (as you need more space here) and one for /swap (but only if you want to use suspend-to-disk; swap is almost never used on my system the rest of the time). /tmp is a ramdisk nowadays so you don't have to care about write processes there.

HTH

Comment: I guess I need to [study TRIM settings](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2010279) for the / partition and that's about it for SSD-related changes to a default install. I want to stick with the install till the next LTS and hence moving /var to HDD, which will give me breathing space on the SSD - don't expect my / to increase - its been in the 5-6 GB range for years now.

Comment: I use suspend a lot every day, so putting swap on the SSD for that purpose helps.