# Using internal SSD for Linux installation

Tags: windows-7, linux, ssd, multi-boot

I have a Samsung NP530 ultrabook. I am planning to dual-boot the Win7 on it with Xubuntu 12.04. The ultrabook has a 500GB Hitachi HDD and a 16GB SanDisk SSD. I can see the HDD in BIOS, but not the SSD. Using GParted from the LiveCD, I could see the HDD and SSD as sda and sdb respectively. The layout is [described here](https://superuser.com/questions/456188/partitioning-scheme-on-hddssd-system).

From [this LinuxMint forums link](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=107546#p605823), it seems that the SSD is used transparently by Win7 to boost its performance.

> Your Windows system probably uses Intel's SRT technology.

Blazing performance on Win7 is not needed - it will be used for the odd Android device rooting utility. If I want to keep dual-boot, and yet use the SSD for Linux, how can I turn off the Intel SRT boosting?

Answer (score 2):

Samsung provides na "Easy Settings" utility (glad I didn't remove all the bloat-ware this time).

In the **General** Tab, **Intel Rapid Start Technology** allows Win7 to save its state to the 4.29 GB SSD partition, just like how Linux swap works.

In the **Express Cache** Tab, **Use the Express Cache** allows DisKeeper to use the 10.61GB SSD partition to function as a cache.

On Linux, we have Flashcache and bcache. They are not for the casual Ubuntu user though. And the SSD cache partition cannot be shared between OSes.

Comment: actually this usually doesn't work like swap. Check this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Matrix_RAID

Comment: Complicated! I meant functionality, like how Linux hibernate saves to the swap partition.